# Ipopt in pyomo google colab

Tags: python-3.x, google-colaboratory, mathematical-optimization, pyomo, ipopt

I tried to use the following code to use ipopt in google colab, but it gave an error.

```
#solver:ipopt
!apt install coinor-libipopt-dev

!pip install ipopt
SolverFactory('ipopt').solve(model).write()
```

```
  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> See above for output.
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  Building wheel for ipopt (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for ipopt
  Running setup.py clean for ipopt
Failed to build ipopt
ERROR: Could not build wheels for ipopt, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

Please, anyone know how to handle the following error, and what should be the code to avoid giving errors?

Comment: The error you are posting is not from the code that you posted above.  the error cites line 8 which is different from your example code.  Be sure you have the executable target correct.  I don't use Google Colab, but on most terminals you can check `which ipopt` and get the correct path

Comment: @AirSquid I tested separatelly here and the error is in the installation of ipopt.
I mean that this error is vinculated to the the following lines: 

!apt install coinor-libipopt-dev

!pip install ipopt ;

Could you help how to fix it ?

Comment: In anaconda it is fine.... but when using in google colab it seems to not being able to... could anyone help?...